# How to write console output of pg_dump to a file in python

Tags: python

Hi All i am trying to log the console output of a pg_dump to a file but unable to do so below is the function i have written

```
import subprocess
def backupOperation():
   p = subprocess.Popen(["pg_dump","-v","-Fc","-d","database_name","--  file","output.dump"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   output, err = p.communicate()
   fo = open("log.txt", "wb")
   fo.write(output)


backupOperation()
```

But my log.txt file is empty.
I am new to python programming,Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with me, but you don't close your file so that may be the problem.

[EDIT] tested with `ls` and that worked. `pg_dump` however writes to stderr. Working code below:

```
import subprocess
def backupOperation():
    p = subprocess.Popen(["pg_dump","-v","-Fc","-d","database_name","--file","output.dump"], 
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = p.communicate()
    print(output)
    print(err)
    with open("log.txt", "w") as fo:
        fo.write(err)

backupOperation()
```

Comment: Its still not working log.txt is empty.FYI i want to log following output of       pg_dump which is printed to console
          pg_dump: reading schemas
         pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator classes
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator families
.....

Comment: what do the print statements say, and you did change `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`?

Comment: thankyou very much yes its working now.pg_dump writes to stderr was really informative once again thanks.